# Accessing SimpleHTTPServer on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, webvr

I'm developing with WebVR and I'm serving my HTML using the `SimpleHTTPServer` on my Mac. I want to figure out a way to access this website on my `iPhone` so I can see what I have created with my `Google Cardboard`.

I looked through a bunch of stack questions and none of them talked specifically about accessing a local website that is being served via `SimpleHTTPServer`

I tried getting my `ip` address and then concatenating the port

```
Ex. xxx.xx.xx.x : 8000
```

But it didn't work :( Also, both my phone and computer are on the same network too

Says `This site can't be reached. IP_ADDRESS took not long to respond`

Answer (score 0):

The way I tried is the correct way. I was using `school wifi` so I'm assuming they're configured in a way that we aren't able to do that. Once I got home and tried on my local connection, it worked like a charm!